# PHP array_fill but with repeating pattern

Tags: php

Is there a built-in function or otherwise elegant way of prefilling an array with a repeating pattern of values.

Essentially what I require is a combination of the `array_fill` and `str_repeat`.

Comment: What is the array you want to make?  Why can't you use `str_repeat` to make it?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to say No. I have never come across anything like this. I think the best thing to do would be your own for-loop that appends values to array in the pattern that you need.

Comment: You may be able to do something more elegantly with array_fill_keys depending on your exact problem/pattern

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function array_pattern($input_array, $repeat_count) {
    $output_array=array();
    for($count = 1; $count < $repeat_count; $count++) {
        $output_array = array_merge($output_array,$input_array));
    }
    return $output_array;
}
```

(will only work for keyed array, not associative arrays, but the whole repeating pattern thing doesn't really lend itself to assoc arrays anyway)

Comment: Perhaps you meant `$input_array` instead of `$rep_array`?